# Что не так с моим class, помогите найти и исправить ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Всем привет. я иучая class на python не могу понять что я е так делаю

```
class Stats():
#Class в котором будут описаны базаве функции 
    def __init__(self, name, demdg, armor, sp, lv):
        #статы которые будут
        self.name = name
        self.demdg = demdg
        self.armor = armor
        self.sp = sp
        self.health = 100
        self.lv = lv

    def show_hero(self):
        #будет выводить статистику
        discription = (self.name + ' урон = ' + str(self.demdg) + ' броня = ' + str(self.armor) + ' мана = ' + str(self.sp) + ' уровень = ' + str(self.lv) + ' здоровье = ' + str(self.health)).title()
        print(discription)

    def lv_up(self):
        #тут будет подниматся уровень
        self.lv += 1

    def demdg_lou(self, armor, demdg):
        self.health -= (demdg // armor)


y.Stats('юля', 10, 1, 13, 1)
```

Comment: Похоже у вас ошибка? Нужно это в вопросе указывать. А так: `y.Stats('юля', 10, 1, 13, 1)` -> `y = Stats('юля', 10, 1, 13, 1)`. А можно и `y = Stats(name='юля', demdg=10, armor=1, sp=13, lv=1)`

Comment: Блин никогда бы не заметил спс

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина в опечатке `y.Stats('юля', 10, 1, 13, 1)`

Правильно будет так:

```
y = Stats('юля', 10, 1, 13, 1)
```

или так:

```
y = Stats(name='юля', demdg=10, armor=1, sp=13, lv=1)
```